# Methods of Subnanometer Distance Measurement

Tags: measurements

How can one measure distances down to the ~0.01nm resolution using standard equipment such as LEDs, lasers, photodiodes, interferometers etc...?

A pulsed diode could be used as a measurement device when coupled with a photodiode sensor, but would it give sub-nanometer resolution?

The measuring device is needed to determine the extension of a nanometer precision actuator (Piezoelectric Actuator.)

Comment: Do you have a particular purpose in mind? In general what you're asking is not possible: interatomic spacings are typically 0.1 nm or larger, and thermal vibrations are typically larger than your 0.01 nm length scale. But we are aware of shorter distances. You'll get a better answer if you are more specific about the purpose of the length measurement you have in mind.

Comment: If you want to measure the change in relative lengths between two arms of an interferometer - then this can be done and has been done - look at LIGO. It can measure a difference in arms lengths down to $10^{-19}m$. If you are interested in measuring the interatomic distances in warm dense matter or other materials up to that precision, then this can be done via measuring XANES.